# Mutliple sums on the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to perform multiple sums on the same dataframe and then concatenate the new dataframes into one final dataframe. Is there a concise way of doing this, or do I need use iteration ?

I have a dict of this form `{key: [list_of_idx], ...}` and need to groupby my dataframe for each key.

## Sample data

```
import random
random.seed(1)

df_len = 5
df = {'idx':{i: i+1 for i in range(df_len)}, 'data':{i:random.randint(1,11) for i in range(df_len)}}
df = pd.DataFrame(df).set_index('idx')

# Groups with the idx to groupby
groups = {'a': [1,2,3,4,5],
          'b': [1,4],
          'c': [5]}

# I'm trying to avoid/find a faster way than this
dfs = []
for grp in groups:
    _df = df.loc[groups[grp]]
    _df['grp'] = grp
    _df = _df.groupby('grp').sum()

    dfs.append(_df)
dff = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Input (df)

```
   data  idx
0     2    1
1    10    2
2     9    3
3     3    4
4     6    5
```

Expected output (dff)

```
     data
grp      
a      30
c       6
b       5
```

Note : I'm stuck with python 2.7 and pandas 0.16.1

### Time result

I tested the proposed methods and calculate the time of execution. I show the mean time per execution (using 1000 executions for each answer):
I couln't test Quang Hoang first answer, because of my pandas version.

```
time         method  
0.00696 sec  my method (question)  
0.00328 sec  piRSquared (pd.concat)  
0.00024 sec  piRSquared (collections and defaultdict)  
0.00444 sec  Quang Hoang (2nd method : concat + reindex)
```

Comment: Can I just say I'm pleasantly surprised and really, really happy to see someone follow some good advice and you using `random.seed(...)` here so everyone can create a reproducible example while still being able to scale input/output to test :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Clever use of `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat({k: df.loc[v] for k, v in groups.items()}).sum(level=0)

   data
a    22
b     8
c     2
```

**NOTE:** This magically works for all columns.
Suppose we have `more_data`

```
import random
random.seed(1)
df_len = 5
df = {
    'idx':{i: i+1 for i in range(df_len)},
    'data':{i:random.randint(1,11) for i in range(df_len)},
    'more_data':{i:random.randint(1,11) for i in range(df_len)},
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df).set_index('idx')
```

Then

```
pd.concat({k: df.loc[v] for k, v in groups.items()}).sum(level=0)

   data  more_data
a    22         42
b     8         19
c     2          7
```

---

#### But I'd stick with more Python: `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

results = defaultdict(int)

for k, V in groups.items():
    for v in V:
        results[k] += df.at[v, 'data']

pd.Series(results)

a    22
b     8
c     2
dtype: int64
```

For this to work with multiple columns, I have to set up the `defaultdict` a tad differently:

```
from collections import defaultdict

results = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

for k, V in groups.items():
    for v in V:
        for c in df.columns:
            results[c][k] += df.at[v, c]

pd.DataFrame(results)

   data  more_data
a    22         42
b     8         19
c     2          7
```

This is what it would look like without `defaultdict` but using method `setdefault` from the `dict` object instead.

```
results = {}

for k, V in groups.items():
    for v in V:
        for c in df.columns:
            results.setdefault(c, {})
            results[c].setdefault(k, 0)
            results[c][k] += df.at[v, c]

pd.DataFrame(results)

   data  more_data
a    22         42
b     8         19
c     2          7
```

Comment: I like the fact that it works for multiple columns (with concat). Possible to do the same with defaultdict ? (I never used it.)

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Let me put together what that looks like.

Comment: @Paulloed I've updated the post with more information for you.

Comment: Thank you for your precise answers ! (seems little bit quicker with `.setdefault()` on a `dict`)

Answer (score 5):

This should be (quite) a bit faster:

```
s = pd.Series(groups).explode()
df.reindex(s).groupby(s.index)['data'].sum()
```

Output:

```
a    30
b     5
c     6
Name: data, dtype: int64
```

---

Update: similar approach for earlier pandas version, although it might not be as fast

```
s = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'grp':a, 'idx':b}) for a,b in groups.items()],
             ignore_index=True).set_index('grp')
df.reindex(s.idx).groupby(s.index)['data'].sum()
```

Comment: That is clever (-:

Comment: Thx for the quick answer, unfortunately, I'm stuck with python 2.7 and pandas 0.16.1 and .explode() was not implemented :( I add the version to my post